# idiomatic way to stack totals plus multiple groupwise results into a single output table

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

i'm curious if there are faster or more elegant ways to start with this data set..

```
# generate some fake data
x <- mtcars[ , c( 1 , 2 , 8:11 ) ]
```

..and construct this table (with overall, gear, cyl, and gear+cyl breakouts).  notice that `dcast` only creates a single set of breakouts, not all of them at once.  so `dcast` can be used to create the 1st, 2nd-4th, 5th-7th, and 8th-15th rows individually but not stacked together.

```
   overall gear cyl 0_0_2 0_0_3 0_0_4 0_1_2    0_1_4 0_1_6 0_1_8    1_0_1 1_0_2 1_0_4 1_1_1 1_1_2
1        1   NA  NA 17.15  16.3 12.62    26 19.26667  19.7    15 20.33333  23.6  18.5  29.1  27.4
2        1   NA   4   NaN   NaN   NaN    26      NaN   NaN   NaN 21.50000  23.6   NaN  29.1  27.4
3        1   NA   6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 21.00000  19.7   NaN 19.75000   NaN  18.5   NaN   NaN
4        1   NA   8 17.15  16.3 12.62   NaN 15.80000   NaN    15      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5        1    3  NA 17.15  16.3 12.62   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 20.33333   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6        1    4  NA   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 21.00000   NaN   NaN      NaN  23.6  18.5  29.1  25.9
7        1    5  NA   NaN   NaN   NaN    26 15.80000  19.7    15      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  30.4
8       NA    3   4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 21.50000   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9       NA    3   6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 19.75000   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
10      NA    3   8 17.15  16.3 12.62   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
11      NA    4   4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN  23.6   NaN  29.1  25.9
12      NA    4   6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 21.00000   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN  18.5   NaN   NaN
13      NA    5   4   NaN   NaN   NaN    26      NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  30.4
14      NA    5   6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN  19.7   NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
15      NA    5   8   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 15.80000   NaN    15      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

here is my solution, but i'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do something like this without my bulky function definition.  thanks!

```
# program start
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

# load your real data here
x$overall <- 1

# define a make-table function that quickly creates overall, cyl, gear, and gear+cyl-level tables using any value and any function
mt <-
    function( x , fun , var ){
        out <-
            rbind.fill(
                dcast( x , overall ~ vs + am + carb , fun , value.var = var ) ,
                dcast( x , overall + cyl ~ vs + am + carb , fun , value.var = var ) ,
                dcast( x , gear + overall ~ vs + am + carb , fun , value.var = var ) ,
                dcast( x , gear + cyl ~ vs + am + carb , fun , value.var = var )
            )

        nsm <- c( 'overall' , 'gear' , 'cyl' )

        out[ , c( 'overall' , 'gear' , 'cyl' , names( out )[ !( names( out ) %in% nsm ) ] ) ]
    }

    # make a table of the defined structure, calculating the mean of the mpg column
mt( x , mean , 'mpg' )
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's a `breakout` and `by= breakout`. Really I don't know what it means.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i am having a hard time describing it.  you see how the first row is "overall" then the 2nd, 3rd, 4th rows are broken out by cyl, then rows 5-7 are broken out by gear, etc.?  those are each a different breakout.  if there's a better way to describe this groupwise thing, i can edit the question..  thanks :)

Comment: `reshape2::add_margins` ? `dcast(..., margins = T)`.  But I don't think I'm providing all the margins you want.

Comment: thanks @hadley :) that's really close.  `dcast( x , cyl + gear ~ vs + am + carb , mean , value.var = "mpg" , margins = c( 'cyl' , 'gear' ) )` provides overall x overall, overall x cyl, cyl x gear, but not gear x overall.  is there any way to get that final combo in the output or am a stuck writing a custom function?

Comment: Take a look at `add_margins` and work from there

Comment: @hadley duh. sorry. thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @hadley for exactly what i was looking for

```
x <- mtcars[ , c( 1 , 2 , 8:11 ) ]
library(reshape2)

y <- add_margins( x , vars = c( 'gear' , 'cyl' ) )
dcast( y , gear + cyl ~ vs + am + carb , mean , value.var = 'mpg' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general version of your code:

```
mt <- function(data, y, x, fun, var) {
  formulas <- paste(y, "~", x)
  casts    <- lapply(formulas, dcast, data = data, fun.aggregate = fun,
                                      value.var = var)
  out      <- rbind.fill(casts)

  nsm <- unique(unlist(strsplit(y, '\\s?\\+\\s?')))
  out[, c(nsm, setdiff(names(out), nsm))]
}

mt(data = x,
   y    = c("overall", "overall + cyl", "gear + overall", "gear + cyl"),
   x    = "vs + am + carb",
   fun  = mean,
   var  = 'mpg')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, flodel!  i guess i'm surprised that there's no way to structure a table like this without building a specific function..  i was hoping there was some trick in `reshape` or `plyr` or `data.table` but i suppose i'll stick with custom functions for now :/